# Google Sheets script filter by sheet name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get a list of sheets which contain a specific word. For example, I have 4 sheets, big tree, small tree, big house, small house and I need to get only the sheets which contains a word "tree". I tried using indexOf function but it did not help. I am new to this, any help will me appreciated. This is what I have tried so far, but it does not work.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
const neededSheets= ["tree"];
   
const filteredListOfSheets = allSheets.filter(s=> neededSheets.lastIndexOf(s.getSheetName()) == 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

This is what you are looking for:

```
function myFunction() {
  
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
const allSheets_names=allSheets.map(sheet=>sheet.getSheetName())  
const neededSheets= ["tree"];   
const filteredListOfSheetsNames = []   
neededSheets.forEach(ns =>               
        allSheets_names.forEach( (as,index) =>
       {if (as.indexOf(ns)>-1){filteredListOfSheetsNames.push(as)}}))                   
const filteredListOfSheets =  filteredListOfSheetsNames.map(name =>ss.getSheetByName(name))   
}
```

### Explanation:

- `filteredListOfSheetsNames` contains the sheet names you
  are looking for and `filteredListOfSheets` contains the sheet
  objects you are looking for.
- Therefore, you can use the elements of `filteredListOfSheets` to
  apply sheet operations e.g. `filteredListOfSheets[0].getSheetName()`.
- Additionally, the code is flexible. Namely, you can have more items
  in the `neededSheets` array: `const neededSheets= ["tree","house"];`