# How can I pull an array of sheet names that do not contain a particular term?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following question/answer appears to answer the question of how to filter a Google Sheets array to those with a particular term in the name:

[Google Sheets script filter by sheet name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620218/google-sheets-script-filter-by-sheet-name/63620670#63620670)

How would I revise this code to filter an array of my sheet names that do NOT contain a particular string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Alternate Method

You can also use the [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) & [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) methods to achieve this.

### Script

```
function sample() {
  /** E.g. you want to filter sheet names that do not contain the word "Name"*/
  var shouldNotContain = 'name';
  var sheetNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(s => s.getName());
  var filtered = sheetNames.filter(x => !x.toLowerCase().match(shouldNotContain.toLowerCase()));
  console.log('Original Sheet Names:\n', sheetNames)
  console.log('Filtered Sheet Names that do not contain the \"' + shouldNotContain + '\":\n', filtered)
}
```

### Demonstration

- Test spreadsheet file

> [image]

- Result

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets that do not include a string

function myFunction(s = "ee") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const allSheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !~sh.getName().indexOf(s));
  const allSheets_names = allSheets.map(sheet => sheet.getSheetName())
  const neededSheets = ["tree"];
  const filteredListOfSheetsNames = []
  neededSheets.forEach(ns =>
    allSheets_names.forEach((as, index) => { if (as.indexOf(ns) > -1) { filteredListOfSheetsNames.push(as) } }))
  const filteredListOfSheets = filteredListOfSheetsNames.map(name => ss.getSheetByName(name))
}
```

Includes sheets whose names do not include `ee`